# Calculate probability 2 random people are in the same group?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, statistics, probability

In my dataset, there are `N` people who are each split into one 3 groups `(groups = {A, B, C})`. I want to find the probability that two random people, `n_1` and `n_2`, belong to the same group.

I have data on each of these groups and how many people belong to them. Importantly, *each group is of a different size.*

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math 

data = {
    "Group": ['A', 'B', 'C'],
    "Count": [20, 10, 5],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

```
  Group  Count
0     A     20
1     B     10
2     C      5
```

I think I know how to get the sample space, `S` but I am unsure how to get the numerator.

```
def nCk(n,k):
  f = math.factorial
  return f(n) / f(k) / f(n-k)

n = sum(df['Count'])
k = 2
s = nCk(n, k)
```

Comment: Would it not be P(both from A) + P(both from B) + P(both from C)?

Comment: https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-probability-of-picking-2-balls-of-the-same-color-and-different-color-when-you-have-1-white-ball-2-red-balls-and-3-black-balls-in-a-bag

Comment: You need to calculate total number of ways of drawing two consecutive balls of the same color *without replacement*.  

This ends up as: `(nCk(n_1, 2) + nCk(n_2, 2) + nCk(n_3, 2)) / nCk(n_total, 2) `

Comment: @James When you say `n_1` are you referring to a person or the number of people in group 1?

Comment: @ Celius: Assume it follows the empirical distribution

Comment: And what is expected answer here?

Comment: Check my answer please, I've edited it!

Comment: `1 - df['Count'].mul(df['Count'].sub(1)).div(2).sum() / df['Count'].prod()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My discrete mathematics skills are a bit rusty so feel free to correct me. You have `N` people split into groups of sizes `s_1, ..., s_n` so that `N = s_1 + ... + s_n`.

1. The chance of one random person belonging to group `i` is `s_i / N`
2. The chance of a second person being in group `i` is `(s_i - 1) / (N - 1)`
3. The chance of both being in group `i` is `s_i / N * (s_i - 1) / (N - 1)`
4. The probability of them being together in *any* group is the sum of the probabilities in #3 across all groups.

Code:

```
import numpy as np

s = df['Count'].values
n = s.sum()
prob = np.sum(s/n * (s-1)/(n-1)) # 0.4117647058823529
```

---

We can generalize this solution to "the probability of `k` people all being in the same group":

```
k = 2
i = np.arange(k)[:, None]
tmp = (s-i) / (n-i)
prob = np.prod(tmp, axis=0).sum()
```

When `k > s.max()` (20 in this case), the answer is 0 because you cannot fit all of them in one group. When `k > s.sum()` (35 in this case), the result is `nan`.

Comment: very clean solution!

Answer (score 1):

I will answer your problem by using hypergeometric distribution, hypergeometric distribution is a discrete probability distribution that describes the probability of k successes (random draws for which the object drawn has a specified feature) in n draws, without replacement, from a finite population of size N that contains exactly K objects with that feature, wherein each draw is either a success or a failure. In contrast, the binomial distribution describes the probability of k successes in n draws with replacement.
So the total probability should be the probability of both belonging to A + probability of both belonging to B + probability of both belonging to C.
This means

```
P(A) = (nCk(20,2) * nCk(15,0))/nCk(35,2)
P(B) = (nCk(10,2) * nCk(25,0))/nCk(35,2)
P(C) = (nCk(5,2) * nCk(5,0)) / nCk(35,2)
```

In code terms:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math 

data = {
    "Group": ['A', 'B', 'C'],
    "Count": [20, 10, 5],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
def nCk(n,k):
  f = math.factorial
  return f(n) / f(k) / f(n-k)

samples = 2
succeses = 2
observations = df['Count'].sum()
p_a = ((nCk(df[df['Group'] == 'A'].set_index('Group').max(),samples)) * (nCk((observations - df[df['Group'] == 'A'].set_index('Group').max()),(samples-succeses)))) / nCk(observations,samples)
p_b = ((nCk(df[df['Group'] == 'B'].set_index('Group').max(),samples)) * (nCk((observations - df[df['Group'] == 'B'].set_index('Group').max()),(samples-succeses)))) / nCk(observations,samples)
p_c =((nCk(df[df['Group'] == 'C'].set_index('Group').max(),samples)) * (nCk((observations - df[df['Group'] == 'C'].set_index('Group').max()),(samples-succeses)))) / nCk(observations,samples)
proba = p_a + p_b + p_c
print(proba)
```

Output:

```
0.41176470588235287
```

Comment: Thanks for the time put into this! I went with the other answer because it's cleaner and faster, though I appreciate the grounding in probability. I knew about the hypergeometric distribution at one time...